# Can you cauterise a wound as it's cut if the blade is hot enough?

Tags: science-based, weapons, anatomically-correct

A person is cutting off an external piece of their body (like an arm or a finger) in a scenario where there is little medical equipment available. The removal of the appendage is an intentional survival choice so it must be done quickly and with as short-a-healing time as possible.

They'd be using something hefty to make the cut, like a cleaver, greatsword, or guillotine, (something that could make the cut in one go as long as the blade were sharp enough) They need to stop the blood flow and minimize infection chances as quickly as possible. If the blade they used to cut was heated until red would this cauterise the wound at the same time as it was cut? Or would it only semi-cauterise the wound? Would it be better to make the cut and then to cauterise the wound as separate procedures?

There would be exceptionally high blood flow so I would have thought cauterising at the same time as cutting would be the best way to control that.

Comment: Yes. Yes you can.

Comment: I didn't mention the appendix or appendicitus in my question.

Comment: There are cautery tools that cauterize even as they cut. But none are used for internal surgery as you've laid it out. @MolbOrg is right, this character is dead. Trained surgeons *might* manage to perform it on themselves in desperate circumstances, and those with lesser training have bumbled through it on occasion. But still need training. Or an auto-surgeon robot (which might be only 20 years away in the real world, for this particular surgery anyway). If instead this is an amputation, that too should be dealt with differently. Stumps ideally need skin sutured over them.

Comment: Editted question to clarify that I am not talking about remvoing an internal organ. I am asking about cutting off an arm or a finger or something external.

Comment: I think people might be confusing `appendage` for `appendix`

Comment: @MolbOrg Even with arms and legs, you want to leave a flap of skin to fold over and suture shut. Cauterizing would interfere with that. Cautery is best for wounds where it's difficult to stop bleeding any other way, for which the flesh can't easily be sewn together.

Comment: @JohnO "you want to leave a flap of skin to fold over and suture shut" - yep, was thinking exactly about that (a scene in a thing I'm reading atm, hand was chopped clean off), but we do not know a cause for actions and goals in OP situation, maybe he will get more proper care later(few days), and chop next 10cm if he is sufficiently lucky. Idk, very questionable solution, very.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cauterising tissue to prevent blood loss during surgery is actually pretty common and is generally done by a technique called surgical diathermy or [electrocautery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauterization#Electrocautery), where the source of heat is a high-frequency current running through a metal probe. It requires quite a lot of power and sustained application though - the amount of heat transferred by the quick slicing motion of a blade may not be enough. You may need to apply the flat of the heated blade to the stump after the cut, if your character can stand the pain, burning, and delicious roast smell.

Note that this only works for small, superficial blood vessels; larger vessels still need to be ligated. The procedure will also cause its own damage to otherwise healthy tissue. Heat will briefly sterilise the cut surface, but unless there is some way to protect and clean the wound afterwards, it will just be quickly re-colonised by skin bacteria and be just as prone to infection, if not more, than a clean blade cut with no heat (large burns are a huge infection risk).

So all in all your character is probably no more likely to survive an emergency amputation with a cold instrument than a hot one. In controlled medical environments, targeted application of heat is a genuinely useful technique, but it’s not really applicable “in the field”. The only advantage I can see is to heat your instruments *before* surgery to ensure they’re clean, but it’s unlikely you’ll be able to maintain surgical sterility anyway.

Comment: If you've seen the docu-series *Star Wars*, you'll notice when someone is cut with a light saber, there's no blood. I assume that's because yes, the saber is hot enough to immediately cauterize the wound.

Comment: I'd like to assume this too, but I think light sabers have properties that we're unableto replicate in real life.

Comment: @BruceWayne actually no, that docu is wrong. I have actually had a (conscious but locally sedated) operation performed on me using an electrified knife. The first part the knife was on a high setting and cut like the blazes while blood flowed freely. Then at the end instead of sutures they turned the heat down and used heat over several seconds to actually cauterize. A lightsaber would flash-vaporize the water content and cause ruptures extending far from the original cut, making a far more deadly bleeding wound than a regular sword.

Comment: @Demigan oh wow, that's really neat. Thanks very much for sharing! I didn't really think about the cauterizing tool being *too* hot but that makes a lot of sense.